# How to Share Mutex Between p_threads in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am quit confused regarding this problem, I have 10 threads which try to insert into a queue.
I want to prevent more than one inserting at the same time using mutex defined globally in queue.h.

I have 2 queues `waiting` and `working` and I just gave it a second though that it's not efficient to give same DS same mutex since this will prevent working on them in parallel even though no problem with that (please correct me if I am wrong).

This means I need mutex for each copy of queue, I tried defining it inside this:

```
struct queue
{
    pthread_mutex_t m; //new
    pthread_cond_t c; //new

    int queue_size;
    struct queue_node *head, *tail;
};
```

but in this case it won't be global so threads can't relate to the same mutex, how can I fix that easily?

If you need this:

```
waiting_buffer = create_queue();
working_buffer = create_queue();


struct queue *create_queue() {
    pthread_mutex_init(&m, NULL); /** initialize mutex **/
    pthread_cond_init(&c, NULL);/** initialize cond **/
    struct queue *q = (struct queue *) malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->head = q->tail = NULL;
    q->queue_size = 0;
    return q;
}
```

Comment: What does "it won't be global so threads can't relate to the same mutex" mean?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica threads share global variables, before I had pthread_mutex_t m; defined in the head of queue.h so it was global, when I insert it into the queue parameters it's not

Comment: Threads share more than just global variables. If they can see the same queue, then they can see the same mutex inside of it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica please see updated version

Comment: Your edit doesn't address anything that I've said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a per-queue mutex and cond var, so you want to include them in the structure returned by `create_queue`. You did this; you just didn't reference them in the `create_queue`.

```c
// Sets `errno` and returns `NULL` on error.
struct queue *create_queue(void) {
    struct queue *q = (struct queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    if (!q)
       return NULL;

    pthread_mutex_init(&(q->m), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(q->c), NULL);
    q->head = q->tail = NULL;
    q->queue_size = 0;
    return q;
}
```